# Дополнительные параметры статьи в joomla 1.5

Tags: xml, joomla, php

Здравствуйте! Сайт на joomla 1.5, потребовалось сделать модуль новостей, который бы выводил "превью" картинку материала (новости). Стандартно в joomla 1.5 у статьи такого параметра нет (как в joomla 2.5).Я добрался до файла /administrator/components/com_content/models/article.xml и добавил в него строчку:

```
<param name="images" type="imagelist" default="" label="Превью картинка" description="DETAILPREWIMG" directory="/images/stories/preview" exclude="" stripext="" />
```

параметр типа imagelist т.е. выпадающий список формируется из  имён файлов указанной директории (directory="/images/stories/preview"), файлы в эту директорию закачивается через обыкновенный медиаменеджер. Проблема в том что при выборе файла картинки и при сохранении материала в выпадающем списке этого параметра выбранным значением остаётся "Изображение по умолчанию" а не имя выбранного мной файла, хотя на самом деле файл к статье прикрепляется правильный, это я вижу из публичной части сайта. Если указать параметр default="" (т.е. файл картинки по умоланию), то всегда выбранным будет именно он, хотя на деле (в публичной части) файл будет тот который я выбрал. Подскажите, как можно сделать чтобы вместо "Изображение по умолчанию" отображалось имя "текущего" файла ? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что за модуль используешь?

Comment: Стандартный модуль "последние новости" , mod_latestnews кажется.

Comment: если использовать тип модуля mod_latestnews, то в Параметрах указывается откуда будут выводиться материалы, необходимо указать или ID Раздела или ID Категории. Так?

Comment: Просто не могу найти, где там картинку можно указывать (выбирать)

Comment: В модуле картинку не указывают. По умолчанию в joomla 1.5 у статью нет миниатюры изображения. Чтобы добавить эту миниатюру я залез сюда /administrator/components/com_content/models/article.xml и после строки <param name="publish_down" type="calendar" default="" label="Finish Publishing" description="DETAILFINISH" /> добавил свой параметр: <param name="images" type="imagelist" default="" label="Превью картинка" description="DETAILPREWIMG" directory="/images/stories/preview" exclude="" stripext="" />
...

Comment: (ту самую картинку) , после чего у меня в админке при редактировании материала появилось дополнительное поле свойств в котором можно выбрать картинку (миниатюру материала). Затем я взял модуль latest news и в /modules/mod_latestnews/helper.php вконце после строки $lists[$i]->created = JHTML::_('date', $row->created, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC2'));  добавил строчку $lists[$i]->prewimg = $row->images; где $lists - список параметров передаваемых шаблону модуля, prewimg - имя нового параметра (придумал сам) , $row - список параметров статьи (из файла article.xml) и $row->images - мой параметр ...

Comment: "миниатюра" (картинка) из того же файла article.xml. Далее в шаблоне модуля /modules/mod_latestnews/tmpl/default.php я просто в нужном мне месте вызываю мою картинку $item->prewimg - это имя картинки с расширением, путь я подставляю заранее /images/stories/preview , его я куазывал в файле  article.xml когда добавлял свой параметр к материалам.

Comment: в один комментарий не уместился )) Вопрост в том что при повторном редактировании материала он в значение миниатюры подставляет не текущую картинку, которую я до этого выбирал, а по умолчанию и естественно после сохранения картинка "слетает". Не пойму как текущую туда подставлять?

Comment: так это ты вывел раскрывающийся список с картинками просто на страницу. А кто будет сохранять картинку в БД? Кто будет добавлять поле в таблицу для этой картинки?

Comment: а может проще заюзать какой-нибудь сторонний модуль, который может выводить превьюшки к статьям? :)